# Multiple cases in one line

Tags: haskell

I've a beginner's question concerning haskell: How can separate e.g. multiple patterns of a case expression in order to put them into one single line? For instance I'd like to write a definition

```
f x = case x of Nothing -> ""
                Just _ -> "123"
```

into one single line? How can this be done? Is the a separation sign? Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can do this on one line, might I suggest not?

There's this lovely function called `maybe` which looks something like

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Which works something like

```
maybe f c (Just x) = f x
maybe f c Nothing  = c
```

So in your case it would just be

```
f x = maybe "" (const "123") x
f   = maybe "" $ const "123"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `f = maybe "" . const "123"`?

Comment: @bheklilr Nope, `maybe` takes a whole function

Comment: Ohh, to be honest, I was looking for function like "maybe". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

You can use a semicolon (`;`) to separate the cases like this:

```
f x = case x of Nothing -> ""; Just _ -> "123"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the usual semicolons:

```
f x = case x of Nothing -> "" ; Just _ -> "123"
```

But I strongly recommend using against it, [it doesn't aid to readability](http://urchin.earth.li/~ian/style/haskell.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, ";" is doing the job. I wanted to write this simple kind of function in a editor and then copy it to ghci. But ghci doesn't like the TABS the second case starts with. Therefore for testing a one line command works fine.

Comment: @dmw64 You can enter multiline code in ghci by using `:{ --code -- :}`

Comment: Ohh, did know that. Thanks you for the hint!